# How to Mock an entity manager

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Am new to unit testing, and just getting started writing unit tests for an existing code base.

I would like to write a unit test for the following method of a class.

```
public int ProcessFileRowQueue()
    {
        var fileRowsToProcess = this.EdiEntityManager.GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess();
        foreach (var fileRowEntity in fileRowsToProcess)
        {
           ProcessFileRow(fileRowEntity);
        }
        return fileRowsToProcess.Count;
    }
```

The problem is with `GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess();` The Entity Manager is a wrapper around the Entity Framework Context.  I have searched on this and found one solution is to have a test database of a known state to test with.  However, it seems to me that creating a few entities in the test code would yield more consistent test results.

But as it exists, I don't see a way to mock the Manager without some refactoring.

Is there a best practice for resolving this? I apologize for this question being a bit naïve, but I just want to make sure I go down the right road for the rest of the project.

Comment: It looks like `his` is the dependency here.  Can that be mocked, and would in turn return a known (also mock) object for `EdiEntityManager`, which itself has a stub of known behavior for `GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess()`?  Since `his` is external to this code being tested, it's the dependency and should be the mock.  Wherever this code gets `his` should be where that mock is injected.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  Should have been `this'

Comment: The same principle still applies, though.  What is `EdiEntityManager`?  Can it be mocked?  It's the external dependency and should be mocked.  Wherever it gets populated into the object, that's where the mock would be injected.  I guess what I mean is, what exactly is preventing you from mocking it?

Comment: Because it is 300 lines of code, 32 methods and seems like a lot of work to mock, but maybe I am missing something about how to mock it.

Comment: I'm not sure you know what a mock is then.  You don't need to re-write it line-by-line, what would even be the point of that?  All you need to implement is the `GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess()` method, and all it needs to do is return a known result (even a hard-coded one).  That's basically a line of code.  Mocking frameworks make it pretty easy to define these mocks/stubs/behaviors as well.

Comment: Great point - I think that is the issue here  :)

Comment: I'd recommend starting with a mocking framework (I personally like RhinoMocks, but any will do) and trying to create a mock for that type and injecting the mock into the object.  For either of those things (creating, injecting), determine what roadblock may exist which prevents it.  (If the class isn't mockable then you may need to wrap it in a mockable interface, if the containing object isn't injectable then you may need to make it injectable.)  The question of "should I mock this" is a simple "yes", but *can you* is another question entirely and the information presented can't answer that.

Comment: Great, thank you.  If you want to post as answer, will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hearing two questions here:

**Should I mock EdiEntityManager?**

Yes.  It's a dependency external to the code being tested, its creation and behavior are defined outside of that code.  So for testing purposes a mock with known behavior should be injected.

**How can I mock EdiEntityManager?**

That we can't know from the code posted.  It depends on what that type is, how it's created and supplied to that containing object, etc.  To answer this part of the question, you should attempt to:

1. Create a mock with known behavior for the one method being invoked (`GetFileRowEntitiesToProcess()`).
2. Inject that mock into this containing object being tested.

For either of these efforts, discover what may prevent that from happening.  Each such discovery is either going to involve learning a little bit more about the types and the mocks, or is going to reveal a need for refactoring to allow testability.  The code posted doesn't reveal that.

As an example, suppose `EdiEntityManager` is created in the constructor:

```
public SomeObject()
{
    this.EdiEntityManager = new EntityManager();
}
```

That would be something that prevents mocking because it gets in the way of Step 2 above.  Instead, the constructor would be refactored to require rather than instantiate:

```
public SomeObject(EntityManager ediEntityManager)
{
    this.EdiEntityManager = ediEntityManager;
}
```

That would allow a test to supply a mock, and conforms with the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Or perhaps `EntityManager` is too concrete a type and difficult to mock/inject, then perhaps the actual type should be an interface which `EntityManager` defines.  Worst case scenario with this problem could be that you don't control the type at all and simply need to define a wrapper object (which itself has a mockable interface) to enclose the `EntityManager` dependency.